# Android Sqlite , Toast Shows Data Inserted but it's not inserted

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into Sqlite when I inerted it says "Inserted" but when I try to feteched the data there but is no Data in database , I have also checked in sqlite browser tables creates but data is not inserted

**Here is my code**

```
fun inserData(user: User) {
        var database = writableDatabase
        var values = ContentValues()
        if (user.Description.equals("CLOTHES")) {
            values.put("TEXT", "${user.Category}")
            values.put("IMAGE", "${user.Image}")
            if (values !== null) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                database.insert(Cloth,null,values)
            }
        }
        database.close()
    }
```

**Fethcing data**

```
fun ClothData(): ArrayList<User> {
    var clothData = ArrayList<User>()
    var db = readableDatabase
    var cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM $Cloth", arrayOf())
    if (cursor !== null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            var user = User()
            user.Description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TEXT"))
            user.Image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("IMAGE"))
            clothData.add(user)
        } while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }
    return clothData
}
```

Comment: did you check the return value of `database.insert(Cloth,null,values)`?

Comment: Yes , I tried to log on Logcat its returning correct values

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteDatabase.insert doesn't promise a row is inserted. You need to check return value > 0.

I always use insertOrThrow() which is better to capture exceptions like constraint error.

Comment: Can you please explain ??

Comment: insert fails to insert in case of exceptions like SQLiteConstraintException -- your row is duplicate with another row in a unique index. In such case insert() returns with negative value. This scenario is ignored in your code. Use insertOrThrow to make sure exceptions are captured.

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue in displaying toast in your insert method. if data do not insert in the `database`. `Toast` will show success.

**Try this**

it will return `true/false` if data is inserted successfully or not.

```
fun addTask(tasks:Tasks): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(NAME, tasks.name)
        values.put(DESC, tasks.desc)
        values.put(COMPLETED, tasks.completed)
        val _success = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
        db.close()
        return (Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1)
    }
```